# Splunk python SDK to upload a CSV file to lookup table of specific destination app

Tags: python, csv, upload, splunk, splunk-sdk

I want to automate uploading a csv file to lookup tables of a specific destination app in my splunk. I can do this from splunk GUI as shown below, however I was trying to find a way to do it from python. I tried the following code which doesn't seem to be correct.

```
path = 'data/inputs/oneshot'
Service.post(path, name=filename, **kwargs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Splunk does not have an API for uploading lookup files.  Go to https://ideas.splunk.com to ask for one.